# Setting f:setPropertyActionListener value with a f:param value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, param, setpropertyactionlistener

I'm trying to use the `setPropertyActionListener` tag to set a value in my backing bean. However, it doesn't work as I expected.

Context: userService is an instance of my backing bean, which contains an int member, reqID. This, in turn, is the key to a map of objects that belong to a class called User. I'm trying to create a page that will list all instances of User, and provide a button to visit a separate view that shows that particular User's information. To do this, I'm attempting to set `userService.reqID` to the id of the chosen User so it can generate a reference to that user for the next view (which is done in the call `userService.toUserInfo`).

If I use the xhtml snippet below:

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid>
                    <ui:repeat value="#{userService.UserList.getUserList()}" var="user">
                        <li>
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
                            <h:commandButton value="View details of #{user.name}" action="#{userService.toUserInfo}">
                            <f:param name="id" value="#{user.id}" />
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{userService.reqID}" value="#{id}"/>
                            </h:commandButton>

                        </li>
                    </ui:repeat> 
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

The tag does not appear to evaluate `id` correctly and I get a Null Pointer Exception.

Earlier, I tried changing my setPropertyActionListenerTag so it read out as:

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{userService.reqID}" value="id"/>
```

which gave me an error, because the tag was sending the string `"id"` as opposed to the int value of the parameter.

Is there some way to force f:setPropertyActionListener to evaluate the expression under `value`? Or is there another tag that will allow me to do this?

Also, is ui:param used appropriately here?

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but shouldn't it have been `value="#{user.id}"` if it was going to work at all? You left out `user` in your example, so how would it know which `id` you're talking about?

Comment: Good point. I had it as `id` to refer to the `ui:param` rather than the `user` member. I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: Yeah, that actually works! Thank you.

Just wondering though, is it not possible to make the `setPropertyActionListener` tag use the `param` value?

Comment: I'm not sure, Steve. I am still learning myself, and [there are lots of ways to achieve similar effects](http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.ca/p/view-parameters-in-jsf-20.html).

Comment: I actually flagged to have this question closed, but now that BalusC has answered it, it's suddenly valuable. Mods, please ignore my flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<f:param>` (and `<ui:param>`) doesn't work that way. The `<f:param>` is intented to add HTTP request parameters to outcome of `<h:xxxLink>` and `<h:xxxButton>` components, and to parameterize the message format in `<h:outputFormat>`. The `<ui:param>` is intented to pass Facelet context parameters to `<ui:include>`, `<ui:decorate>` and `<ui:define>`. Mojarra had the bug that it also behaves like `<c:set>` without a scope. This is not the intented usage.

Just use `<c:set>` without a scope if it's absolutely necessary to "alias" a (long) EL expression.

```
<c:set var="id" value="#{user.id}" />
```

Put it outside the `<h:commandLink>` though. Also in this construct, it's kind of weird. It doesn't make the code better. I'd just leave out it.

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener ... value="#{user.id}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Setting ui:param conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372421/setting-uiparam-conditionally/)
- [what is the scope of <ui:param> in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228282/what-is-the-scope-of-uiparam-in-jsf/)
- [Defining and reusing an EL variable in JSF page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434866/defining-and-reusing-variable-in-jsf-page/)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, if you're using EL 2.2 (as you're using JSF 2.2, you undoubtedly are as it requires a minimum of Servlet 3.0, which goes hand in hand with EL 2.2), then just pass it as bean action method argument without `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` mess. See also a.o. [Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/invoke-direct-methods-or-methods-with-arguments-variables-parameters-in-el) and [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-parameter-of-current-row-to-commandlink-inside-datatable)

```
<h:commandButton ... action="#{userService.toUserInfo(user.id)}">
```

On again another unrelated note, such a "View user" or "Edit user" request is usually idempotent. You'd better use `<h:link>` (yes, with `<f:param>`) for this. See also a.o. [Creating master-detail pages for entities, how to link them and which bean scope to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/creating-master-detail-pages-for-entities-how-to-link-them-and-which-bean-scope) and [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o).

Oh, that `<h:panelGrid>` around the `<ui:repeat><li>` doesn't make sense in HTML perspective. Get rid of it and use `<ul>` instead. See also [HTMLDog HTML Beginner tutorial](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/).

Comment: I unfortunately can't upvote yet, but thank you!

Also, your tutorials have been really helpful.